# How to reference parent Javascript Revealing Module Pattern object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, kendo-ui

Im implementing the Revealing Module Pattern with KendoUI's observable object. Here is the [Jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/gwHkv/5/) to the Module definition.

The problem I have is when the datasource is retrieved locally (as in the jfiddle example) it works fine, but when I set it to retrieve remote data it doesnt work. Here is the [jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/VbnAx/1/) for the remote data code (this wont work in jfiddle regardless because it wont be able to connect to my webapi but you get the point).

The problem seems to be in the Change event of the datasource. When the data is local it all seems to execute sequentially so when you reference this or self than it is talking to the viewmodel. When using remoting it calls back into the change function but doesnt seem to be referencing the correct object anymore and when I set selectedContact it does nothing to the bound objects on the form.

Does anybody have any ideas how I should be referencing the selectedContact object in the Change method of the datasource object? Or advice on where im going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue that you're trying to use `json` instead of `jsonp`.  You can read up on `jsonp` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  Based on what you're describing about it working locally vs remotely, that'd be my guess as to where the issue is.  Try changing the data type of your data source from `json` to `jsonp`:

```
transport: {
       read: {
           url: $('#urlLink').data('url') + '?tenantID=1&dataType=Contacts_Details',
           dataType: "jsonp",
           data: {
               actionName: function () {                        
                   return SelectedContactID;
               }
           }
       }
   }
```